# Target only one provider in a security realm for a deployment?

Tags: security, weblogic, weblogic12c

Weblogic 12.1.2

I have a security realm with 2 different authentication providers defined. One provider is an LDAP server for an internal application. The other provider is a SQL Authenticator for an application that will be publicly available.

For security reasons, I want the public application's deployment to only utilize the SQL Authenticator provider (vice-versa is a nice to have). Is there a way to define this restriction within the deployment descriptor for my deployment? If not, is there another alternative that would provide some kind of separation?

Alternatives I have seeked out:

1. Separate security realms. One with LDAP, one with SQL Authenticator - Does not seem to be an option as only one security realm can be active for the domain at one time.
2. Second Adjudication provider - Does not seem to be an option as only one adjudication provider can be active at one time.

Comment: Can you simply reorder the Authentication provider to suit your need? Weblogic will check them in order... so unless you have some sort of cross-over, set the SQL authentication to be first and your LDAP provider second.

Comment: I agree with the solution outlined above.. as long as you order the Authenticators correctly and set the flag to Sufficient, this should work.

Comment: This would work if I could have a different order per deployment or server, but I don't believe this is an option - one order per domain.

Comment: Weblogic 12.2.1 fixes this issue, allowing multiple **active** security realms per domain. The solve was creating 2 security realms, targeting them to separate domain partitions, then targeting the appropriate servers to those partitions.